# Let $G=GL_2(\mathbb C)$, and let $H=\{\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ 0&c \end{pmatrix}, a,b,c \in \mathbb C \}$. Show conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=GL_2(\mathbb C)$, and let $H=\{\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ 0&c \end{pmatrix}, a,b,c \in \mathbb C \}$. Show that any element in $G$ is conjugate to some element in $H$.

So it seems that it's based on matrix similiarity, but how do I actually use this to prove this claim?

Thanks!

Comment: See: Jordan form.

Comment: I think this is a case of Schur's Theorem (for upper triangularization of linear operators). Check out Theorem 8.7 on p. 192 of Steven Roman's _Advanced Linear Algebra_ for a proof for any finite dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose an ordered basis whose first element is an eigenvector. In terms of that basis, the matrix will be in that form. Remark that there is always an eigenvector, since the complex numbers are algebraically closed.